# Matrix size Determination

Tags: matrix, xquery

im supposed to work with xQuery and determine a matrix size. The Matrix has the format:

```
<matrix>
    <row>
        <c>1</c>
        <c>2</c>
        <c>3</c>
    </row>
    <row>
        <c>4</c>
        <c>5</c>
        <c>6</c>
    </row>
</matrix>
```

and what im currently trying to do is this:

```
xquery version "1.0"  encoding "UTF-8"; 
module namespace wob="http://wob.iai.uni-bonn.de/exercises/xquery/matrix";

declare function wob:dimensions($ma as element(matrix)) as xs:integer* {
    let $m := fn:count($ma/row)
    let $tmp := (for $currentRow in $ma/row
        return count($currentRow/c))

    let $result := ($m, $tmp[1])

    $result = (for $i in (2 to count($tmp))
        if ($tmp[1] != $tmp[$i])
        then return ()
        else ()
    )

    return $result
};
```

coming from java, in my understanding this should return an empty sequence in case of unequal row widths. Because i want to return the matrix dimensions only if it is a valid matrix.

parsing this with saxon, i get the error

```
Error on line 11 column 3 of matrixops.xqm:
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...lt := ($m, $tmp[1]) $result#:
    expected "return", found "$"
```

does this mean i cant assign it like that, or do i have to return something?

besides, is there an ide to do this? seems very hard to learn to syntax because to me its really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax problem, you're missing another `let` before `$result`. Furthermore, you forgot the colon in the assignment.

```
let $result := (for $i in (2 to count($tmp))
```

Comment: sorry, i got what you meant with your code, but i dont get where i am missing the colon. Would you mind integrating it in the code for me? :)

Oh well, figure it out thanks so much, you are a life saver